# deserialized object has no value

Tags: c#, json, uwp, json.net, uwp-xaml

#### Source Code - `Main class`

```
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine(responseBody);

        var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GasInformation>(responseBody);
        
        LowGasFees.Text = deserializedObject.SafeGasPrice;
```

#### Source Code - `GasInformation class`

```
public  class GasInformation

{    
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public static int status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LastBlock")]
    public static int LastBlock { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SafeGasPrice")]
    public static string SafeGasPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ProposeGasPrice")]
    public static int ProposeGasPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FastGasPrice")]
    public static int FastGasPrice { get; set; }
}
```

#### Json

```
{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":{"LastBlock":"14276296","SafeGasPrice":"65","ProposeGasPrice":"65","FastGasPrice":"67","suggestBaseFee":"64.251201854","gasUsedRatio":"0.999343233333333,0.308395633333333,0.161141266666667,0.843474233333333,0.501605648750662"}}
```

#### Problem

It seems from my perspective that the object `deserializedObject` has no value and is causing the application to crash.

Comment: should those be string instead of int?

Comment: Why have a `JsonProperty` attribute if the only thing is does is say _"serialize XxxProperty as XxxProperty"_.  It just makes for more typing (and, having information in two places makes maintenance more error-prone)

Answer (score 1):

you have a wrong class for deserialization. try this

```
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(responseBody);
```

classes

```
public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public long Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public Result Result { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Result
    {
        [JsonProperty("LastBlock")]
        public long LastBlock { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SafeGasPrice")]
        public long SafeGasPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ProposeGasPrice")]
         public long ProposeGasPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("FastGasPrice")]
        public long FastGasPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("suggestBaseFee")]
        public double SuggestBaseFee { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gasUsedRatio")]
        public string GasUsedRatio { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I haven't checked this out, but it looks right.  Not sure why someone down-voted it.  Whether or not `"status":"1"` will get deserialized into an `int` (or `long` or some other numeric type) is up to the serializer (I believe that the first System.Text.Json iteration didn't do this).  I think that `"status": 1` is clearer

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, I am agree with you. I changed SuggestBaseFee to double too. About another int I think post owner should decide what to do. GasUsedRatio can be changed to double[]  too, but I don't  know maybe it should be shown in a view this way.

Comment: IMHO the answer lacks details of what the OP has done wrong. `you have a wrong class for deserialization` doesn't really go into context as to *why*. Can you explain your changes as you *made other property changes*.

Comment: @Trevor who are you to decide what type is good and what is wrong? Let post owner to decide it. I am sure he would be able to change it to int if it is nedeed or can ask me without your help. I am translating json the way it is.

Comment: @Trevor Instead of waisting my and somebody else time for argument,  post your answer, nobody prohibits you. And I will down vote it because it is not string. Do you think it is a good idea to interfer with people who is trying to help?

Comment: It only returns zero.

Comment: I'm suggesting improvements to your answer, not only to benefit the OP, but anyone else that may come along.  Can we not post comments for clarification and or suggestions?

Comment: @summitg Did you use my classes ?  I always test the code before posting and this code  is working properly at my computer. Did you check  Debug.WriteLine(responseBody) ? it should be ABSOLUTELY the same as a json you posted. If there is a difference pls correct the json.

Comment: Yes, I've implemented your classes and it only returns zero.

Comment: @summitg yes, I am agree, but  you should  down vote only in the case when code can not be compiled even. Only in this case it is uselles.

Comment: @summitg I am sorry but nobody can help you in this case. I can only ask you to try var p= Newtonsoft.Json.JObject.Parse(responseBody); Is it working?

Comment: Hello, I've tried to implement but the `JObject` method doesn't exist.

Comment: Try to add  " using  Newtonsoft.Json; " to the  top of the code and install using nugget if it gives an error too.

Comment: I'm using `using Newtonsoft.Json` and I've installed it with `nuget` but it appears that the method `JObject ` doesn't exist.

Comment: @summitg Try to add  using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Comment: Is working but only returns zero.

See screenshot.
https://imgur.com/a/cPKIr7F

Comment: @summitg What returns zero? Parse can not return zero. And I can see the whole json too

Comment: When I try to use the name field `LowGasFees.Text = deserializedObject.SafeGasPrice.ToString();` it returns zero.

Comment: @summitg What it has to do with JObject.Parse?

Comment: It's nothing to do with JObject.Parse?  I'm only saying it is returning zero.

Comment: @summitg you'll want `LowGasFees.Text = deserializedObject.Result.SafeGasPrice.ToString();`, `SafeGasPrice` is a property in `Result` class. Honestly, you shouldn't be able to compile with that code if you're not using the classes in the answer above.

Comment: @Trevor I hope now you see what kind of problem  with post owner all the time and now much patience I need. This is why  I became very upset when people are talking what is better int or string.  And BTW as a matter of fact string is better then double in this case since it will not need double conversation.  But we still don't know where else this property is used. and you will see that the answer will be never accepted.

Comment: @summitg "LowGasFees.Text = deserializedObject.SafeGasPrice.ToString();" How it can return zero? It will never be even compiled. What tools are you using?

Comment: `deserializedObject.Result` class doesn't appear in the IDE.

Comment: JetBrains Rider + Normal UWP Default Project + Nuget Package: Newtonsoft.

Comment: @summitg You must be trolling? What classes are you using? Can you see Result in my Data class?

Comment: I can only see `Result` when using `GasInformation` but not `deserializedObject`

Comment: @summitg I was sure it was abacus.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model has two problems.

#### Hierarchy

The first problem with your data model is that it is **not** modelling your json. In your json you have a hierarchy. If you format your json for example via an online [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) then you should see something like this:

```json
{
   "status":"1",
   "message":"OK",
   "result":{
      "LastBlock":"14276296",
      "SafeGasPrice":"65",
      "ProposeGasPrice":"65",
      "FastGasPrice":"67",
      "suggestBaseFee":"64.251201854",
      "gasUsedRatio":"0.999343233333333,0.308395633333333,0.161141266666667,0.843474233333333,0.501605648750662"
   }
}
```

- As you can see you have three top level nodes: `status`, `message` and `result`
- `LastBlock`, ... , `FastGasPrice` are defined under the `result` node

Your models should represent this hierarchy as well. There are websites (like [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/)) which can help you to generate draft C# data classes.

Or you can also use [Linq2Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to do the mapping manually.

#### static properties

The other problem is that you have declared your properties as `static`. Even though `DeserializeObject` can deal with them, most probably you don't need them to be static.

By the way: `deserializedObject.SafeGasPrice` << This should cause compile time error since you can't access `static` member through an instance object.